# What does the `#with_items` method do for a ViewComponent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view-components

I'm editing a feature that renders a ViewComponent.

After the ViewComponent is rendered, it's passed a block, which is the component itself

```rb
render SomeComponent.new(arg: foo) do |component|
  component.with_items(some_items.map { |item| Hash }
end
```

There doesn't seem to be a tremendous amount of documentation for the `#with_items` method and I'm wondering:

## is `#with_items` method a way to render slots inline?

I've done some simple and advanced Googling

I've reviewed the ViewComponent documentation (searching for "with_items" only points to a single test case situation using `with_item`...singular)

I've searched the Github repo for ViewComponent and saw some allusion to the method, though it wasn't much help to me.

It appears to be an inline way to pass items to the template and or object without explicitly defining a slot with `renders_many`, though that's just my expectation.

Comment: "without explicitly defining a slot" - then how exactly are your rendering it?

Comment: "items" is being used in the template and also in the object. Exactly: a method called `filtered_items` in the object is iterating on "items", which is not referenced anywhere else in the object. In the template `filtered_items` is called and performs iteration with "items"

Comment: you might want to use [`method`](https://rubyapi.org/3.3/o/object#method-i-method) to find where your methods are defined: `<%= method(:filterend_items) %>`. there is no `filtered_items` method in view components and you can't use `with_items` without having a slot defined.

Comment: `#filtered_items` is a method in the `component.rb`. Within that method is a call to `items.reject do |item| `.

Comment: `component.rb` this is not part of view component, this is your code. you probably just have `items` slot defined for every component in a superclass.

Comment: so i'm able to have a view component without a component.rb file? I'm dubious. I thought the entire paradigm was to have (at least) 2 files for every ViewComponent: component.rb and component.html.erb. Unless Im mistaken. Either way, you're absolutely correct, I just found a superclass that `renders_many :items`.

Comment: if you have `SomeComponent` then you should have `some_component.rb`, corresponding template is optional (you  could just define `render` method if it's a small component). when you said `component.rb` this came to mind (superclass for all components) https://github.com/primer/view_components/blob/main/app/components/primer/component.rb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256800/discussion-between-j-r-bob-dobbs-and-alex).